# LuaLaTeX pdf: Labelled equations in a two columns not working

Tags: equations, multicolumn, subequations, equation-number, annotate-equations

Trying to get this to come out as two columns of labelled equations however, I've got misaligned columns vertically. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{natbib} % used for bibliography
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx} %more advanced tables
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

To calculate these properties the following equations were used:
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{align}
        &\text{Axial Strain:}&\epsilon_{a}&=\frac{\delta L}{L_{0}}\label{eq:AxialStrain} \\
        &\text{Volumetric Strain:}&\epsilon_{p}&=-\frac{\delta V}{V_{0}}\label{eq:VolumetricStrain}\\
        &\text{Radial Strain:}&\epsilon_{r}&=\frac{\epsilon_p-\epsilon_a}{2}\label{eq:RadialStrain}\\
        &\text{Deviator Strain:}&A&=\epsilon_a+\frac{\epsilon_p}{3}\label{eq:DeviatorStrain}
    \end{align}
    \begin{align}
        &\text{Adjusted Area:}&A&=A_0\frac{1-\epsilon_p}{1-\epsilon_a}\label{eq:AdjustedArea}\\
        &\text{Radial Stress:}&\sigma_r&=\sigma_3\label{eq:RadialStress}\\
        &\text{Deviator Stress:}&q&=\frac{P}{A}\label{eq:DeviatorStress}\\ 
        &\text{Axial Stress:}&\sigma_a&=\sigma_r+q\label{eq:AxialStress}\\
        &\text{Volumetric Stress:}&p&=\frac{\sigma_a+2\sigma_r}{3}\label{eq:VolumetricStress}
    \end{align}
    \end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]

I started with one align but that just puts all the equations in one column. And the issue with using just align and not using multicols is that you can only set one label to each line, not to each equation

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not need to guess what you are doing.

Comment: @Mensch sorry not sure how to do that, please can you explain?

Comment: @WillDuke see this [link](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: should be better now, thanks for the feedback

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/78132456/2777074

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The floating (5) comes from the `\\` after `\label{eq:DeviatorStrain}`

LaTeX equations should not start a new paragraph, and it is the case here since they're enclosed in `multicols`. Simply add `\noindent` before.

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{natbib} % used for bibliography
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx} %more advanced tables
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

To calculate these properties the following equations were used:
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \noindent
    \begin{align}
        &\text{Axial Strain:}&\epsilon_{a}&=\frac{\delta L}{L_{0}}\label{eq:AxialStrain} \\
        &\text{Volumetric Strain:}&\epsilon_{p}&=-\frac{\delta V}{V_{0}}\label{eq:VolumetricStrain}\\
        &\text{Radial Strain:}&\epsilon_{r}&=\frac{\epsilon_p-\epsilon_a}{2}\label{eq:RadialStrain}\\
        &\text{Deviator Strain:}&A&=\epsilon_a+\frac{\epsilon_p}{3}\label{eq:DeviatorStrain}
    \end{align}
    \begin{align}
        &\text{Adjusted Area:}&A&=A_0\frac{1-\epsilon_p}{1-\epsilon_a}\label{eq:AdjustedArea}\\
        &\text{Radial Stress:}&\sigma_r&=\sigma_3\label{eq:RadialStress}\\
        &\text{Deviator Stress:}&q&=\frac{P}{A}\label{eq:DeviatorStress}\\
        &\text{Axial Stress:}&\sigma_a&=\sigma_r+q\label{eq:AxialStress}\\
        &\text{Volumetric Stress:}&p&=\frac{\sigma_a+2\sigma_r}{3}\label{eq:VolumetricStress}
    \end{align}
    \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, that works :)